# Can't get this very simple AngularJS Hello World to work in Internet Explorer 9+

Tags: angularjs

I cannot get this simple example to work on IE9+.  It works fine in firefox and chrome. Thanks for the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Hello World, AngularJS - ViralPatel.net</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    Write some text in textbox:
    <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

    <h1>Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>

    <h4>Uppercase: {{ sometext | uppercase }}</h4>
    <h4>Lowercase: {{ sometext | lowercase }}</h4>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE8 works. What's the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding this line of code in the head:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Hello World, AngularJS - ViralPatel.net</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! It works. Can you explain what that does?

Comment: Sure, you're probably inside a corporate network that automatically defaults IE to compatibility mode.  Adding IE=edge makes your IE run as the latest version, so it would run as whatever it is instead of compatibility mode.